# Equivalent classes of sets (Is my solution correct)?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Equivalence relation between two sets is defined as |S1|=|S2|.
Use the equivalence defined above to partition the set {4, 5, 6, 34, 90, 87, 65, 21, 35, 22} into equivalence classes.

From what I understand we can have equivalence relations between two sets and the number of elements in the set can be from 1 to 11. This would mean there are equivalence classes such as [4]=[5]=...=[22]={4,5,6,...,35,22} and then [{4,5}]=[{5,6}] = ... ={members are sets of two elements}.

This would make the solution too big and uninteresting. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

The question is from peter linz's textbook "An Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata". The relation is defined in question 1.1.4 and the question in context is given in 1.1.14

Comment: Are you looking to partition the *set* $\{4,5,6,\dots,22\}$ or are you more likely trying to partition **the power set of the set**...  If you are looking to partition the set, it doesn't really make sense as none of the elements are sets themselves (under common interpretations) and you have not defined how the relation acts between non-sets.  Further, you have the number $21$ appearing twice in your set, is this intentional?  If trying to partition the powerset, you have forgotten also to consider the equivalence class of $\emptyset$.

Comment: As for partitioning the **powerset** of the set, i.e. partitioning the set $\mathcal{P}(\{4,5,6,\dots,35,22\})$, according to the relation $\sim$ where $A\sim B$ iff $|A|=|B|$ then you are correct that the equivalence classes will be broken up according to how many elements are in each set.  Ignoring the redundant $21$, there are $2^{10}$ elements in the power set and there are $\binom{10}{k}$ elements in the equivalence class corresponding to the sets with $k$ elements each.  Yes, there are a lot.  No, you are not expected to write them all out.

Comment: @JMoravitz It is supposed to be only one 21. I've edited the question a bit. In case it seems ambiguous can you help me understand what it is trying to say?

Comment: @JMoravitz It says only "partition the set {....}". So is the proper answer [4]=[5]=[6] = { all elements}. So, there is only one equivalence class?

Comment: If the set were $\{ \{4\}, \{5\}, \{6\}, \{34\}, \{90\}, \{87\}, \{65\}, \{21\}, \{35\}, \{22\} \}$, THEN you could say that $[\{4\}] = [\{5\}] = [\{6\}] \dots [\{22\}]$ and thus there would be one equivalence class. The issue is that that the elements of your set are not sets themselves and thus the equivalence relation doesn't apply to them.

Comment: You must have copied the question incorrectly, there must have been a typo, the question itself is written badly, you must have copied the relation from one problem and the set from a different problem, or (*much less likely*) they are treating the natural numbers as sets themselves (*how they are constructed in the first place in ZFC*).  Our equivalence relation is defined between two **sets**.  $4$ is not a set (*usually*).  We have not been told whether $4$ is related to $5$ and have no way of knowing using what you have written.  It is undefined.

Comment: Using a completely different equivalence relation, say for example the equivalence relation $\star$ where I define $x\star y$ if and only if $x-y$ is a multiple of two, then you see that $4$ is related to $6$ is related to $34$ etc... while $5$ is related to $87$ is related to $65$ etc... We can partition $\{4,5,6,34,\dots,22\}$ into the sets $\{4,6,34,90,22\}$ and $\{5,87,65,21,35\}$.  If the relation was $x\sim y$ iff $x$ and $y$ have the same final digit, then it would be partitioned differently as $\{4,34\},\{5,65,35\},\{90\},\{21\},\{87\}$ etc...

Comment: @JMoravitz That's what confused me. The relation has been defined on two sets and not natural numbers. The question is from peter linz's textbook "An Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata". The relation is defined in question 1.1.4 and the question in context is given in 1.1.14

Comment: @JMoravitz Maybe the trick is to find out the flaw in the question?

Comment: There is no "trick."  Now that we see how the problem is exactly written from the book, we see that you misinterpreted the phrasing of which relation you were supposed to refer to.  Exact wording is very important.  If they tell you to look at *example 1.1.4* then do not look at *exercise 1.1.4* as they are different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact wording of the question (*according to the fifth edition of the book*):

[image]

Notice that this comes from the list of **EXERCISES**, not *Examples*

[image]

We are not wanting to use number $4$ above.  As mentioned, this is not an equivalence relation on the set in exercise $14$.  We are instead directed to **EXAMPLE 1.4** below:

[image]

So, partition the set $\{2,4,5,6,9,23,24,25,31,37\}$ according to the relation $\equiv$ where $x\equiv y$ if and only if $x\mod{3}=y\mod{3}$

> Group all of the multiples of three together, group all of the numbers which are one more than a multiple of three together, and group all of the numbers which are two more than a multiple of three together.

---

As an aside, if you have an electronic version of the book, the blue highlighted phrase $\color{blue}{\text{Example 1.4}}$ is in fact a hyperlink which can be clicked taking you straight to the intended location.